# XHR responses no longer shown for errors in DevTools

Tags: php, apache, php-ini

Bit of an odd one, but my development activity has been crippled by the loss of error messages in my DevTools. It was working yesterday, and from what I can see nothing on my system has changed.

The issue isn't browser related as it's impacting Chrome, FireFox and Edge; none of them display errors any more:

[image]

I saw in another SO question that someone had xDebug installed which was apparently caused this same issue for many folks. I also had it installed and believe I have removed it completely (perhaps there are remnants of its config somewhere?). Unfortunately I'm no better off from removing it.

Now that I can safely say the issue isn't browser related, I guess it can only be either my PHP config or Apache(WAMP) config?

The following PHP functions are compiled on my development environment, but I also wrote them at the top of my broken script for good measure and it made no difference.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

PHPInfo() confirmed that I'm showing and logging PHP errors also:

[image]

I got a little fed up so I uninstalled WAMP64 and installed the latest version (I know, taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut...) and it hasn't helped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this problem rear it's ugly head on any other websites you visit? I ask because some custom application extensions can cause this issue as well.

Comment: I'd need a website with an XHR responding with an error... maybe I can get a test script on one of the web servers. I'll check and come back to you.

Comment: While I'm doing that, which extensions are you referring to? Browser extensions? Because this is affecting all browsers (some without any extensions at all)

Comment: I experienced a similar issue when using the Redux Devtools `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` extension instantiated in the code itself, so yes and no. Check to see if you  have a code declared developer extension

Comment: Right click request, open in new tab. See how it goes.

Comment: What is the response headers showing?